How to change node edit's DELETE button to redirect to the node delete page instead of the JS popup?
We'd like to change the functionality of the DELETE button at the bottom of a node's edit page to redirect to the node's dedicated delete form instead of displaying the JS popup confirmation.
This is because we have a custom block on the delete URL (/node/NID#/delete) that displays extra help text and warnings that we manage through a custom block.
We have access to the node's actions via hook_form_alter() but I'm not sure how to change the functionality to redirect to the /node/#/delete url when clicked.
screenshot shows dpm($form['actions']['delete']);



Removing the 2 data-dialog attributes should do it I think. The button is already set to go to the correct URL. The dialog functionality is sitting ontop of this. So if you remove it then it should go to the usual delete URL

Perfect, thank you!
